# Extract class description between <td>

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am performing some data web scrapping using `Beautiful Soup` in Python. How is it possible to extract the class information between `<td>` when there is no text provided ? See the example I am working on. I'd like Beautiful Soup to provide me the text `mm_detail_N`, `mm_detail_N`, `mm_detail_SE`.

```
<tr>
<td class="caption">Direction du vent</td>
<td><center><div class="mm_detail_N" title="title.wind_N"></div></center></td>
<td><center><div class="mm_detail_N" title="title.wind_N"></div></center></td>
<td><center><div class="mm_detail_SE" title="title.wind_SE"></div></center></td>
</tr>
```

I usually use the following command

```
data = [i.get_text(strip=True) for i in soup.find_all("td", {"title": "title_of_the_td"})]
```

I have tried the following commands:

```
data = [i.get_text(strip=True) for i in soup.find_all("div", {"title": "caption_of_the_td"})
```

The command executes properly but the outcome is **empty**

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you mentioned above that you would like to extract `mm_detail_N, mm_detail_N, mm_detail_SE`. So you can select the common class attr value `div[class*="mm_detail"]` then invoke .get() method to pull the that value as text form as follows:

```
html_doc = ''''
<tr>
<td class="caption">Direction du vent</td>
<td><center><div class="mm_detail_N" title="title.wind_N"></div></center></td>
<td><center><div class="mm_detail_N" title="title.wind_N"></div></center></td>
<td><center><div class="mm_detail_SE" title="title.wind_SE"></div></center></td>
</tr>
'''

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, 'lxml')

for td in soup.select('div[class*="mm_detail"]'):
    print(td.get('class'))
```

**Output:**

```
['mm_detail_N']
['mm_detail_N']
['mm_detail_SE']
```